# LUIS builtin number entity for German culture completely ignores decimal separator -> BUG?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

The English number format 1,000,000.90 is 1.000.000,90 in German.

In English culture LUIS interpretes the number as 1000000.9

But in German culture LUIS interpretes the number as 10000009
I.e. it completely ignores the decimal separator!

This is a bug, right?

[image: Here is the correct English interpretation]

[image]

Comment: are you sure the question is related to robot framework tag?

Comment: Ups... I wanted to use #botframework. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LUIS predefined entities/intents are useful, but may not fulfil all purposes. You can try doing the matching yourself with a regex entity or to have a preprocessing step in your pipeline, where you check for numbers and format them correctly so LUIS will understand (using regex, plain code, NLP library...)

Comment: I absolutely agree. But not considering decimals in German language in contrast to e.g. English language is probably not how it should be.